# How to get bookmark page number of PDF with iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I use the code below to get the page number of the bookmark, but the returned page number is incorrect,

```
var names = pdfDoc.GetCatalog().GetNameTree(PdfName.Dests).GetNames();
var newestBookmark = GetBookmarks(pdfDoc.GetOutlines(false), pdfDoc, names).LastOrDefault();
private static IDictionary<string, int> GetBookmarks(PdfOutline outline, PdfDocument pdfDoc, IDictionary<string, PdfObject> names)
{
    if (outline == null)
    {
        return pdfOutlines;
    }
    var inner = outline.GetAllChildren();
    if (inner != null && inner.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in inner)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(item.GetTitle(), out DateTime title))
            {                        
                pdfOutlines.Add(item.GetTitle(), pdfDoc.GetPageNumber((PdfDictionary)outline.GetDestination().GetDestinationPage(names)));
            }
            if (item.GetAllChildren() != null && item.GetAllChildren().Count > 0)
            {
                GetBookmarks(item, pdfDoc, names);
            }
        }
    }
    return pdfOutlines;
}
```

Any other ways to get the page number?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to go through the page outline, traversing the hierarchy using `PdfOutline`'s children in order to traverse them recursively.

To find the page number by a page object, you should use `pdfDocument.getPageNumber(PdfDictionary).`

The method walking through the outlines may look as following:

```
void walkOutlines(PdfOutline outline, Map<String, PdfObject> names, PdfDocument pdfDocument) 
{
    if (outline.getDestination() != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(outline.getTitle() + ": page " +
                pdfDocument.getPageNumber((PdfDictionary) outline.getDestination().getDestinationPage(names)));
    }
    for (PdfOutline child : outline.getAllChildren()) 
    {
        walkOutlines(child, names, pdfDocument);
    }
}
```

The main entry point where you call the method to traverse the root:

```
PdfNameTree destsTree = pdfDoc.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.Dests);
PdfOutline root = pdfDoc.getOutlines(false);
walkOutlines(root, destsTree.getNames(), pdfDoc);
```